# don't link html <input> with js model and java model

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

I have a login page with some code.

```
<div ng-show="!loggedIn()">
        <form ng-submit="login()">
            Username:
            <input type="text" ng-model="userName"/>
            Password:
            <input type="password" ng-model="userPassword"/><span><input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Login links with userName model in js file and userPassword - not.

```
$scope.login = function() {
                $scope.error = null;
                mainService.login($scope.userName, $scope.userPassword).then(function(token) {
                    $scope.token = token;
                    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
                    $scope.checkRoles();
                },
                function(error){
                    $scope.error = error;
                    $scope.userName = '';
                    $scope.userPassword = '';
                });
            };
```

...

```
 appModule.service('mainService', function($http) {
        return {
            login : function(username, userpassword) {
                return $http.post('/user/login', {name: username}, {password: userpassword}).then(function(response) {
                    return response.data.token;
                });
            },
```

I have some controller with inner class

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static class UserLogin {
        public String name;
        public String password;
    }
```

and method login()

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public LoginResponse login(@RequestBody final UserLogin login)
    throws ServletException {
    System.out.println(login.name + login.password);//
```

Here login.name = what I wrote in web page (Login) and login.password always = null.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You omitted the relevant code: `mainService.login`.

Comment: depends on how you send data ... default `$http` uses Content Type application/json not form encoding. Show service method

Comment: added in the question

Comment: You either need to change the contentType sent or receive the request body as json

Comment: yes, when I changed type password to text - it works, but password should not be visible

Comment: Everything works. Thank's to all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The login function has to change like this:

```
login : function(username, userpassword) { return $http.post('/user/login', {name: username, password: userpassword}).then(function(response) { return response.data.token; });
```

Comment: I added in the question where I see login and password values

Comment: Okay, look at chrome network tab and see what data is being sent when you click on the login button. That might give you clues as to what the client is sending to the server. This should help debug further.

Comment: What's the difference compared to OP code? Should be an explanation of what was changed and why... not just `like this`. Proper indent would make this readable too. I don't see how this resolves OP server side issue

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is because your POST call is passing the password as the configuration parameter in `$http.post`. Your password should be part of the data parameter object:
`$http.post('/user/login', {name: username, password: userpassword})`